# Java AWT Rectangle intersection

Tags: java, awt, rectangles, intersect

I have two Rectangles:

```
Rectangle rectZR = new Rectangle(513, 163, 38, 39); //(x,y,width,height)
Rectangle rectCorrect = new Rectangle(76, 206, 44, 44);
```

and I do:

```
Rectangle intersect = rectZR.intersection(rectCorrect);
```

As the coordinates show, the two rectangles actually do not intersect, but Java still returns me an intersection and `intersect` has the following dimension (x,y, width, height):

```
513, 206, -393, -4
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You use the **intersects** method if you want to know whether or not the rectangles intersect.  The intersection method returns a Rectangle whether or not the rectangles intersect.  If the width and height are both negative, the rectangles didn't intersect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) on intersect method states:

> Computes the intersection of this Rectangle with the specified
>   Rectangle. Returns a new Rectangle that represents the intersection of
>   the two rectangles. **If the two rectangles do not intersect, the result
>   will be an empty rectangle**.

While JavaDoc for the whole class specifies:

> A Rectangle whose width or height is **negative** has neither location nor
>   dimension along those axes with negative dimensions. Such a Rectangle
>   is treated as non-existant along those axes. **Such a Rectangle is also
>   empty** with respect to containment calculations and methods which test
>   if it contains or intersects a point or rectangle will always return
>   false. Methods which combine such a Rectangle with a point or
>   rectangle will ignore the Rectangle entirely in generating the result.
>   If two Rectangle objects are combined and each has a negative
>   dimension, the result will have at least one negative dimension.

So, rectangle created by intersection with both negative dimensions actually means that there is no intersection. You can check this with `intersects()` method:

```
boolean intersects = rectZR.intersects(rectCorrect);
```